# User defined function interprets date differently depending on whether I reference a cell or enter the date manually

Tags: vba, date, parameters, user-defined-functions

I have a user defined function with 3 parameters. The first 2 are dates and the third the type of inputs I want to reference for further calculations.

If I try to use the function by reference the cells: Ex: `Function(B2,B5,Type1)`, it computes the function as expected. However if I try by entered the dates manually: Ex: `Function(09/09/2022,07/18/2022,Type1)`, I get a value I know to be erroneous.

I have defined both of the parameters as dates within my user defined function and am unsure why this error is occurring.

Comment: What regional settings are you using? What is your system date format?

Comment: For literal dates, you'll need to enclose them within hash signs ( # ), for example `#09/09/2022#`

Comment: `09/09/2022` is `1/2022` or 0.000495